# how to add a null value to an int in ssis C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

```
METHOD_ID = listItem["METHOD_ID"].ToString();
Output0Buffer.METHODID = Int16.Parse(METHOD_ID);
```

How would you add null to the value  and convert to int
if the request value from my SharePoint is null ?

Comment: Define what valid int value null should be then and change null to that value explicitly.

Comment: if the records value is null then it should be null :)?

Comment: An int can't be null. null != 0